# I trying to create external bank (PHP)account but i am not getting any response.Neither i am getting error nor the account is created

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
function stripe_bank_payment()
{
    $this->load->database();
        $id = $_GET['user_id'];  
    $acc_id = $_GET['stripe_account_id'];
    $amount = $_GET['amount'];
    $get = $this->db->select('*')->where(array('user_id' => $id))->get('bank_detail');
    $pay = $get->result_array();

    foreach ($pay as $res) {
      $token = $res['token'];
     }

    require_once 'stripe/init.php';

    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_6zdfZQ6R0Jh7EiFONJTpYaFl");

    $account = \Stripe\Account::retrieve($acc_id);      
    $account->external_accounts->create(array("external_account" => $token));           
    return $account;

       }
```

The above is my code.
I am trying to create external bank account.
user_id, stripe_account_id, and amount is given by me.
the token which is to be used is there in bank_details table.
So i am getting token from there.
And then running the code.

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: the account is not being created.
I m getting no response.

Comment: Are you getting only one $token or multiple $tokens ?

Comment: @BibhudattaSahoo
Only one token sir.

Comment: Then the issue will be in the API

Comment: i did'nt get it.

Comment: will u plizz elaborate and explain me. @BibhudattaSahoo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148282/discussion-between-jaspreet-singh-and-bibhudatta-sahoo).